# Calling Function Itself in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function like below

```
$.fn.testFunction = function (options) {

    $(window).resize(function () {
       //call testfunction again
    });

    alert("Test");

}
```

If the window size changes, I want to call testFunction again. How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update:* I just realized that you have options as well.

```
$.fn.testFunction = function _testFunction(options) {

    $(window).resize(function () {
       _testFunction(options);
    });

    alert("Test");
}
```

Comment: IIRC, some browsers don't support "named anonymous" functions or don't keep the scope of `_testFunction` as small as hoped. It may be better to use the longer, explicit variant (create named function in self-executing closure, use that name to recurse and to register).

Comment: @delnan: I did not know that. Could you tell me a browser like this?

Comment: @delnan: all browser do just fine about named function expressions. One downside is IE<8 (probably 8 aswell) which leaks memory for those constructs.

Comment: Ah okay, then I misread or misremembered something. Excuse the confusion.

Comment: IIRC (I'm pretty sure I do) some browsers has problems with named functions which are also assigned to a variable/property

Comment: @shesek: Please provide a version please!

Comment: I just looked it up, and http://kangax.github.com/nfe/ has a great explanation about all the quirks in some browsers. It seems like it *kinda* works on all them, but JScript is using them completely wrong - the named function is treated as both as a completly regular function declaration and as function expression causing all kind of weird stuff (see "JScript bugs"). Safari 2 freaks out if you use named expression unless anywhere other than in assignment (see "Safari Bugs"). Not a lot of space here to expand on that - see the post, it has an excellent in-depth explanation about NFE.

Answer (score 0):

Your function gets stored in `$.fn` object, so you try calling it from there again:

```
$.fn.testFunction = function (options) {
    $(window).resize(function () {
       $.fn.testFunction();
    });

    alert("Test");
}
```

Comment: Take care about the `options`!